# How to run service on boot w/ non-root Ubuntu user

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, systemd

I have a non-root user (no sudo access) on an Ubuntu 14.04 box (Upstart v1.12.1) and I have a script I want to execute after the box has started up.

I've added a `~/.init/demo.conf` file containing my Upstart job configuration.

Without having root access to the box, is it possible for my non-root Upstart job to be detected and ran on boot?